# Make first matched value in the dropdown as default in vue(element ui)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, frontend, element-ui

```
Framework used: Vue and Element UI
```

**Mission:** To display the first matched value as default.

**Problem:** If Texas is selected from the common states, it shows Texas from the all states section when opening the dropdown(both should be selected as both have same values which is correct, the working is totally correct).

**Approach:** I have tried to hide the all states list when the value is present in the common states but it is not the desired outcome.

**Desired Outcome:** If Texas is selected and is in the common states, I would like to show that as default while opening the dropdown(in the common states section instead of the all states section). Is it possible to do so?

**Link to Codepen:** https://codepen.io/limbe_me/pen/BaMwRNz

**Boilerplate:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-select v-model="selectedState" placeholder="Select a state">
      <el-option-group label="common states">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in commonStates"
          :label="item"
          :key="item + '_common'"
          :value="item"
        ></el-option>
      </el-option-group>
      <el-option-group label="all states">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in allStates"
          :label="item"
          :key="item + '_all'"
          :value="item"
        ></el-option>
      </el-option-group>
    </el-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedState: "",
      commonStates: ["California", "New York", "Florida", "Texas", "Hawaii"],
      allStates: [
        "Alabama",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California",
        ".....",
        "Washington",
        "West Virginia",
        "Wisconsin",
        "Wyoming"
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Your methods go here
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <el-select v-model="selectedState" placeholder="Select a state" @visible-change="change">
      <el-option-group label="common states">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in commonStates"
          :label="item"
          :key="item + '_common'"
          :value="item"
        ></el-option>
      </el-option-group>
      <el-option-group v-if="enabled" label="all states">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in allStates"
          :label="item"
          :key="item + '_all'"
          :value="item"
        ></el-option>
      </el-option-group>
    </el-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      enabled: false,
      selectedState: "",
      commonStates: ["California", "New York", "Florida", "Texas", "Hawaii"],
      allStates: [
        "Alabama",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California",
        ".....",
        "Washington",
        "West Virginia",
        "Wisconsin",
        "Wyoming"
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Your methods go here
    change(isVisible) {
      this.enabled = isVisible
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.app {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Add `v-if="enabled"` to your `allStates` option group. Then set it `true` when dropdown is visible

In `ElementUI` document, I saw they have `visible-change`. So you can hook that event up and set `enabled` to `$event`

Here the **Codepen**: https://codepen.io/duckstery/pen/QWYqOQo

---

For your extend request, I've adjusted mine code

```js
  data() {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      selectedState: "",
      commonStates: ["California", "New York", "Florida", "Texas", "Hawaii"],
      allStates: [
        "Alabama",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California",
        ".....",
        "Washington",
        "West Virginia",
        "Wisconsin",
        "Wyoming"
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Your methods go here
    change(isVisible) {
      if (this.commonStates.includes(this.selectedState)) {
        this.enabled = false;
        this.$nextTick(() => (this.enabled = true));
      }
    }
  }
```

Set default `enabled` to `true`

You'll have to check if the `selectedState` is included in `commonStates`. If `true`, set `enabled` to `false` and set it to `true` in the `nextTick`

Here the **Codepen**: https://codepen.io/duckstery/pen/wvNrmMm

Comment: it somewhat solves the problem but there is another issue again. for example an uncommon state is chosen such as "Alabama" on start(selectedState: "Alabama"). It doesn't scroll down to its selected option but shows list of common states and then only the list of all states(where you find your selected state somewhere along the list).

Comment: I've edited the answer to suit your need

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you